# Convert list of lists into single nested row of a data.frame or tibble (R)

Tags: r, list, tibble

I have a nested list of lists:

```
data = list(a = list(1, 2, 3), b = list("foo"), c = list("toast", "onions"))
```

How can I convert this into a single row of a data.frame or tibble? I would like the lists with more than one element (`a` and `c` here) to be kept as lists, and the single-element (`b`) to be a regular value.

Expected output is:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  a          b     c         
  <list>     <chr> <list>    
1 <list [3]> foo   <list [2]>
```

Comment: `tibble::enframe(data) %>% tidyr::pivot_wider()` ?

Comment: Yes, that works for me Ronak. Thanks for your help. What would be the best way to then convert column b to a regular character column? I have tried `... %>% mutate(b = map(b, unlist))`, but this doesn't change the actual column type.

Comment: [Ronak] + `%>% tidyr::unnest(b) %>% tidyr::unnest(b)`

Comment: Thanks Ronak. Also works if I change `map` to `map_chr`, i.e. `... %>% mutate(b = map_chr(b, unlist))'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enframe` + `pivot_wider`

```
tibble::enframe(data) %>% tidyr::pivot_wider() 
#      a          b          c         
#  <list>     <list>     <list>    
#1 <list [3]> <list [1]> <list [2]>
```

To get length one column as vector we can add :

```
library(dplyr)

tibble::enframe(data) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider() %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = ~if(length(unlist(.)) == 1) unlist(.) else .))

#      a          b     c         
#  <list>     <chr> <list>    
#1 <list [3]> foo   <list [2]>
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
> as_tibble_row(Map(function(x) ifelse(length(x)==1,unlist(x),list(x)),data))
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  a          b     c
  <list>     <chr> <list>
1 <list [3]> foo   <list [2]>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data[] <- lapply(data, function(x) if (length(x) == 1) x[[1]] else list(x))
data.table::setDF(data)

# > str(data)
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ a:List of 1
#   ..$ :List of 3
#   .. ..$ : num 1
#   .. ..$ : num 2
#   .. ..$ : num 3
#  $ b: chr "foo"
#  $ c:List of 1
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ : chr "toast"
#   .. ..$ : chr "onions"
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to create a two column dataset with `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(values ~ ind, stack(data), list)
```